# SharePoint Online Add-In workflow tasks do not appear in "My Tasks"

Tags: sharepoint, task, sharepoint-2013, add-in, mysite

I have created a SharePoint provider hosted application. In the SharePoint Add-In, I've created a custom workflow that creates tasks in a new workflow task list hosted in the App Web.

I'd like the tasks to appear in "My Sites" tasks list so that all of my tasks from SharePoint host, apps, etc. are aggregated together.

Is there any way to use the host web tasks list in a SharePoint Add-In workflow, or any way to add the App Web to the task aggregation in "My Sites"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not plan anything related to My tasks as they are obsolete and will be removed soon. Actually they should be removed already (4th of September 2015). See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2998445